# Embedded Jetty Caching JSPs in an Unknown Location

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a trivially simple embedded jetty instance with a mapped JspServlet.  For performance reasons, Jetty is caching the compiled JSP files somewhere, but I can't find the cache location.

When in production, caching is great.  In development, however, I need to remember to run "find . -exec touch {} \;" on my webapp, which is an incredible hack.

Anyway, does anyone know where the jetty cache is?  Didn't seen anything in the documentation.  I looked in /tmp, ~, my working directory, and my webapp directory; didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty stores the generated file in the tmp directory  This will normally be the directory specified by the system property java.io.tmpdir.  On UNIX-like systems this will normally be /tmp

Comment: Also worthwhile reading https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/ref-temporary-directories.html  about how to control the tmp location and its persistence

Comment: The prior answer on managing the webapp temp directory is also useful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19232771

Answer (score 0):

Jetty does not manage JSPs being run under Jetty.

The Jasper/Glassfish JSP implementation being used by Jetty is doing the management of the JSPs.
Specifically the org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet is doing all the work.

There are many configurables for the JspServlet, see the [JSP How-To wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP#Configuring_JSP) for details on all of the configurables.  Looks like the `scratchDir` parameter is what you are looking for.