# Jetty: How to change startup temp directory

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to deploy a vaadin application to jetty.

But when I run jetty using `start.jar`, it starts to a subfolder of

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-Application.war-....`

Although I've put it into `C:\Program Files\MyApp`, it always runs there - including the files it saves.

How do I tell jetty to start right where it resides, and have all files relatively to this base?

I'm on Windows 7, we're talking about the most recent, standalone jetty package.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jetty needs a working directory.

Its search order for finding a work directory is as follows:

1. If the [WebAppContext has a temp directory specified](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.45.v20220203/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setTempDirectory(java.io.File)), use it.
2. If the ServletContext has the `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` attribute set, and if directory exists, use it.
3. If a `${jetty.base}/work` directory exists, use it *(only valid for Jetty 9.1+)*
4. If a `${jetty.home}/work` directory exists, use it.

- *Note:* starting with Jetty 9.1 this test is now `${jetty.base}/work`

5. If a ServletContext has the `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.basetempdir` attribute set, and if the directory exists, use it.
6. Use `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` and use it.

The easiest one is either **#3** or **#4**, just create a `work` directory underneath your `${jetty.home}` or `${jetty.base}` and restart Jetty.

The next easiest is **#6**, to specify your own `java.io.tmpdir` when you start the JVM for Jetty.

```
[jetty-distribution]$ java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/web/work -jar start.jar
```

The rest require you to configure the context for that deployed webapp.

Example for Jetty 7 or Jetty 8:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
                           "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath"><Property name="foo"/></Set>
  <Set name="war">/var/web/webapps/foo.war</Set>
  <Set name="tempDirectory">/var/web/work/foo</Set>
</Configure>
```

Example for Jetty 9 (just a dtd change):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
                           "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath"><Property name="foo"/></Set>
  <Set name="war">/var/web/webapps/foo.war</Set>
  <Set name="tempDirectory">/var/web/work/foo</Set>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually solved my problem. I've chosen to create a `work/` directory. regards

Comment: will this solution also work for embedded jetty server ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above suggestion, if you are setting up jetty as a initd service on Linux and setting up environment variable at /etc/default/jetty then you can add the "TMPDIR" variable to set the temporary directory path.