# Hawtio stops working after running for days

Tags: jetty, hawtio

We are using hawtio to have a fancy and nice web interface for seeing JMX MBeans and Camel Route in our project. However, we have noticed that after weeks running Hawtio stops working and we are getting a Jetty error when trying to access it.

We are using hawtio in standalone mode, version 1.2.0/offline. Also I guess it worth to mention that our Camel routes are pretty heavy and consume many resources (not sure if that impacts hawtio). When trying to access we get this:

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /ourContextPath/. Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty://

It seems like there is no active resource for our context path and I something went wrong like a thread stopped working or something.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this or how to find what's causing this? Also, is this a known bug fixed in the latest version (1.2.1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty needs a work/temp directory to operate.

Default behavior is to use whatever `java.io.tmpdir` points to.

However, on many unix installations, this points to `/tmp`, and that directory is often cleaned out by other processes.

To fix, either specify a `java.io.tmpdir` to be somewhere other than `/tmp`

```
$ java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/run/jetty -jar start.jar
```

or create a `${jetty.base}/work/` directory *(if running Jetty 9.1+)*
or create a `${jetty.home}/work/` directory *(if running versions of Jetty prior to 9.1)*

See the answer at [Jetty: Starts in C:\Temp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232182/jetty-starts-in-c-temp/19232771#19232771) for more details on how this work/temp directory operates and is configured.

Comment: Nice answer! I would have never thought about this, good catch :) I have already checked few things and this seems to be the issue. Thanks!