# Zimbra 8 - java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, zimbra

We have been getting `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file` since yesterday for our **Zimbra** server based on **Ubuntu**.

Despite that nothing is changed; everything had been going well until yesterday. Now the web user interface of Zimbra is not rendered; we get `500 internal server error` in Firebug.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds like file or file system corruption.

Comment: any ideas to solve? @StephenC

Comment: Do a file system check (e.g. `man fsck`).  Check the class file (or JAR file) that the exception messages says is corrupted.  Then try to figure out how your system got into that state.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is setup on default configuration.

It unpacked your war file into the system temp directory, likely `/tmp`.

Some other process then cleared out the `/tmp/` directory, rendering your active runtime invalid.

See other answer about [setting temp / work directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19232771/775715) for more information.