# How to change the temporary directory in jetty9?

Tags: java, jetty

I want to make a temp directory for my jetty and change the default `/tmp` directory to mine temp directory, I tried this

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jetty/temp
```

When I want to start my jetty and it worked, but I'm looking for a way to change the temp directory once and for all. Is there any configuration or xml or something that I can change?

Answer (score -1):

Are you wanting to change the working directory for your webapp?  or the overall temp directory for all processes that might be running under Jetty?

For the webapp specific case, see [the prior answer about changing the temp directory for webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19232771/775715).

For all processes in jetty, add the following 2 lines to your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

```
--exec
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jetty/temp
```

> Note: this will cause `jetty-dist/start.jar` to fork a new process for
>   Jetty server.

Comment: I want to change the overall temp directory for all processes that might running under jetty,I added this two lines to my start.ini,but it makes no dif

Comment: What version of Jetty? and how *specifically* are you starting/configuring Jetty?