# Jetty stops responding after some period of time

Tags: webserver, jetty

I have a project with jetty webserver.
The app is up and works fine. After some period (don't know exactly when) if I try to access the app I receive:

> "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try
>   again later."

The app has schedulers set as well. I would be suspicious for timeout but it's not the case. By analyzing the logs I noticed: 2017-12-08

> 12:45:24.566:WARN:oejsh.ErrorHandler:qtp1555845260-195: Error page
>   loop /error/not-found.faces.

I don't see any other logs which can cause the issue. Any suggestions for solution?

Comment: The message you are receiving "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable." is not something Jetty will say.  That is coming from somewhere other then Jetty.   The log message is valid though.  Are you perhaps deployed on a Unix machine?

Comment: yes I am using a unix machine. The problem is that jetty is up and running properly. Sometimes couple of days, sometimes just a day. There is no time defined when it goes down by itself and I don't have a clue what causes it going down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely case is that you have the default work/temp directory setup in your Jetty deployment **and** there is a process on your machine that periodically cleans up the system temp directory.

Would suggest you specify the work directory or the temp directory (either jvm temp, jetty.base temp, or webapp temp).

See previous answers on how to configure the work / temp directory.

- [How to change the temporary directory in jetty9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319201/how-to-change-the-temporary-directory-in-jetty9)
- [Jetty: Starts in C:\Temp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232182/jetty-starts-in-c-temp)