# HttpServletResponse getWriter() write function starts to throw nullpointer exception after a few days?

Tags: http, post, servlets, jetty, httpserver

I have implemented the following servlet post function on a jetty server. In the HttpServletResponse, it will just write some string.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write("some json string");
    response.getWriter().flush();
}
```

Everything was fine in the beginning. But after some time (a few days; i was not using it and just kept the jetty server running), the servlet starts to throw null pointer exception on the line `response.getWriter().write("some json string");`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.write(ResponseWriter.java:246)
```

I don't know what went wrong. But after a restart of the jetty server, the problem was gone. Do you guys know why?

Comment: What exact version of Jetty are you using?

Comment: jetty-distribution-9.4.22.v20191022

Answer (score 0):

To answer the NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.write(ResponseWriter.java:246)
```

It seems that you gave the Writer a null `String`.

See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.22.v20191022/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ResponseWriter.java#L246

The part where you say Jetty stops working after a few days is likely because you have a process on your machine that is periodically cleaning out the system temp directory, removing content out from underneath Jetty.

See: [Jetty stops responding after some period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757814/775715)

The NullPointerException is like is likely because the write failed and you didn't check for that fact.

[`HttpServletResponse.getWriter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter--) returns a [`java.io.PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Using the various `.write()` methods will never throw an error or exception.

You need to use [`.checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError()) method to know when the write has failed.

This is an old-school API decision on `java.io.PrintWriter` that is actually quite awkward.

See: [PrintWriter and PrintStream never throw IOExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297303/printwriter-and-printstream-never-throw-ioexceptions)

Comment: i guess the issue is that PrinterWriter returned from getWriter() is null. But how?

Comment: AH – the writer is not null. the string is.