# How to tell jetty to extract part of the jar files into its context temp location

Tags: java, jar, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have embedded Jetty into my Java application and i create a executable jar file.When i execute jar file from cmd jetty server is started.I defined following in Jetty server starter class.

```
protected void configureWebApp() throws IOException {
        File webAppDir=new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());

      WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext(webAppDir.getPath(), "/");
        resetTempDirectory(context, currentDir);
        context.setInitParameter("development", "false");
        server.setHandler(context);
        }

protected void resetTempDirectory(WebAppContext context, File currentDir) throws IOException {
        File workDir;
        if (workPath != null) {
            workDir = new File(workPath);
        } else {
            workDir = new File(currentDir, "work");
        }
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(workDir);
        context.setTempDirectory(workDir);
    }
```

when running from `cmd` webAppDir set path pointed to my application jar.so jetty will extract all jar content into its temp directory.It seems like i wasting the resource and slow down my application startup.

Inside my jar it has a `webApp` folder that contains the web releated stuff.My questions are,

1. How can i instruct jetty to tell only extract `webApp folder` into
   temp directory?
2. I can turn off the jetty extraction into temp directry and write my
   own method to extract folder i needed and point that folder as jetty temp
   directory.I am not sure if this a good idea.

I am newbie to jetty please let me know how to do this.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to not allow the Servlet Spec temp directory to do its thing, but still use the Servlet Spec?

See [prior answer on how the temp directory works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232182/jetty-starts-in-c-temp/19232771#19232771).

**Option #1**

This is embedded-jetty, skip the `WebAppContext` (and its Servlet Spec mandated behavior) and configure everything via Handlers (like the `ServletContextHandler`).

You'll lose some ability to "discover" components, and have no bytecode scanning, but you'll be in ultimate control and startup will be measured in sub-second timing.

**Option #2**

If this is just a startup issue, then ignore the temp directory issue, run the `quickstart` generation of the servlet manifest before you deploy, and start your WebAppContext using the (prebuilt) quickstart metadata.